# Forcing website to have the desktop website from meta browser function HTML

Tags: html, browser, scrollbar, responsive, viewport

I have built my own website. `https://mcsimi.netlify.app`.

Currently on Mobile there's a issue with scrolling through the website because you cant scroll past the first div because then there are for whatever reason two scrollbars.

If I set the website to request desktop website with the meta function from every browser it works fine. Can i do it so this desktop site will always be loaded. It's the same file but different browser settings.

This is the meta code I have:

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta name="description" content="Portfolio by McSimi. A Fullstack Developer.">`
```

I tried anything with viewport and it doesnt work right. I exspect it to only have one scroll bar on mobile so i can scroll through the whole page.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Also please try to write as clearly as possible. I assumed `aA` was `meta` when I corrected your post

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want their to be a scrollbar on mobile, just use media queries, at a the screen size you don't want it, use this:

```
body,html::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
      background-color:transparent;
    }
```

to hide the scrollbar.